# max(array) in python not returning the correct value if the elements have decimal values

Tags: python

Say, I have a file "list.txt" which contains:

```
23.21
9.79
9.78
9.75
30.53
```

And here's my python script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

f=open("list.txt")
array=[]
for line in f.readlines():
        array.append(line)
f.close()
print "max value: ", max( array )
```

My expected max value is of course 30.53
But, it returns

> max value:  9.79

You see, I am just starting in python.. Why does it read the max value as 9.79?

Comment: I think you'd need to convert all lines to the float datatype explicitly. By default, python reads lines as strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is so because you are using lexicographical ordering.

Try replacing:

```
array.append(line)
```

with:

```
array.append(float(line))
```